# python-telegram-bot ERROR 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Below is an example of the telegram bot.
Help me understand why function ***message_handler*** works in my code, and ***greet_user*** - not working.

There is a error from error_log decorator: `'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'`

```
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, CommandHandler
from telegram.utils.request import Request


def log_error(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f'Error: {exc}')
            raise exc

    return wrapper


def message_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(text='Example')


@log_error
def greet_user(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('hello')

def main():
    req = Request(connect_timeout=0.5)
    t_bot = Bot(
        request=req,
        token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        base_url='https://telegg.ru/orig/bot',
    )
    updater = Updater(bot=t_bot, use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', greet_user))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters=Filters.all, callback=message_handler))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is it supposed to have the `callback` kwarg? Like so    `dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', callback=greet_user))`

Comment: I tried it, but it didn 't help

Comment: what version of telegram-bot you running?

Comment: version python-telegram-bot = 12.4.2

Comment: I ran your code on mine on Python 3.7 and it works fine. I can't seem to figure out what the error is! Maybe install the latest version of the package and python.

Comment: And the bot is working?

Comment: I haven't tested if its working or not. But I don't get the error above, which suggests to me that it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was .
If we use `use_context=True` in `Updater`, we should pass arguments to the function this way:

```
def greet_user(`update: Update, context: CallbackContext`):
    update.message.reply_text('hello')
```

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0